# If в switch или как сделать по-другому?

Tags: android, switch

Добрый день! У меня есть Expandable navigation drawer и, собственно, обработчик нажатий, выраженный через switch/case.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            String selectedItem = ((List) (mExpandableListData.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))))
                .get(childPosition).toString();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedItem);               

            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:

                            if (условие)
                            {
                                оператор1;
                                оператор2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                оператор1;
                                оператор2;
                            }

                            break;
                        case 1:                                

                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:

                            break;
                        case 1:

                            break;                                                      
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return false;
        }
    }
    );
}
```

И меня все устраивает, но, появилась необходимость и сейчас я объясню какая. У меня есть фрагмент с 2-мя кнопками. Этот фрагмент открывается во фрейме основной разметки (которая загружается в OnCreate) и хотя в коде нет, чтобы его не увеличивать, я в "case 0" вызываю этот фрагмент с 2-мя кнопками. По нажатию на одну кнопку или вторую вытаскивается разный текст, поэтому в разметке фрагмента с кнопками есть TextView куда и вытаскивается он. Проблема в том, что текст этот разный в зависимости от "case" меню. Поэтому нужно как бы создать еще один switch в case 0, в case 1 и т.д. Но я не понимаю как, поэтому подумал воспользоваться if/else как я написал в коде. Только что прописать в условии? И хотя в приложении только в этом суть - в переключении в меню и этими кнопками для вызова текста - не будет ли заметна потеря производительности для пользователя? Да коряво, но я новичок, поэтому планирую сделать сначала так, а потом уже правильно и выпустить в обновлении. Спасибо!

Comment: Если только я правильно понял проблему, - предложу следующее: Есть какие то состояния системы (1,2,3 ...) Мы могли бы создать массив, который содержит Текстовую строку для каждого состояния. И вместо `case` использовать `.Text = Массив[НомерСостояния]`